# How do I hide sub-domain URL in Google Search console?

Tags: google-search-console

I have a site at `abc.samplesite.example` and I want to hide a link `abc.samplesite.example/link` from Google search results.

The console had me verify ownership at `samplesite.example`, when I enter the link I want to hide the console prepends `samplesite.example` to create a garbage link `http://samplesite.example/http://abc.samplesite.example/link`.

Answer (score 2):

In Google Search Console, have you added `abc.samplesite.example` (the subdomain) or have you only added `samplesite.example`? To adjust anything about the subdomain, you'll need to add the subdomain as its own property. Google Search Console will assume the page you are inputting to the Remove URL tool exists on the property domain (which is why you are seeing the pre-pend).

As well, if you are wanting to remove a URL from Google search results the better answer is to add a meta "noindex" tag (http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html) to the page vs. using the Remove URLs tool in Google Search Console. The Remove URLs tool is temporary (https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419?hl=en).

Comment: That was it! Thank you for your help note that I will also be adding noindex but need to remove the  as soon as possible.  Best ian

Comment: Cool. What I'd do is add the subdomain to Google Search Console, use the remove tool to temporarily hide. Then, noindex the pages. That way you get the immediate for the remove URLs (or mostly immediate) and then the longer term noindex as well.